# Как добавить slug в CreateView?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

У меня есть модель `article`, в нем есть `slug`. Как мне создавать модель с `CreateView`, и генерировать `slug` через `slugify`?

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.text import slugify

from .models import Article, Theme
from .forms import ArticleCreateForm

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'article/index.html')


class ArticleCreate(CreateView):

    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleCreateForm
    template_name = 'article/article_form.html'


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Article
    template_name = 'article/article_detail.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models


class Theme(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique_for_date='date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ArticleCreate(CreateView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleCreateForm
    template_name = 'article/article_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug'] = slugify(kwargs['title'])          
        return context
```

P.S. Стандартный `slugify django` не поддерживает кириллицу, если вы предполагаете записи на русском языке, то лучше используйте:

```
pip install pytils
```

views.py:

```
from pytils.translit import slugify
```

Comment: я бы добавил к ответу, что так же нужно изменить `urls.py`, что бы передавать новый slug для `view`. Плюс помимо генерирования slug для view, так же передавать его в создаваемую форму, например как тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/62902229/7186864